# Python, threading issue when using pysimplegui and tkPDFViewer

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter, pysimplegui, pdf-viewer

I'm new to Python and I'm running into a "RuntimeError: main thread is not in mainloop", I understand it is a threading issue, something to do with using PySimpleGui and tkPDFviewer together. Sample code below creates a main window, opening the pysimplegui window by itself is fine, opening the PDF window by itself is fine. However after opening the pysimplegui window the PDF window then throws the runtime error and refuses to open. Any advice would be appreciated.

```
import tkinter as tk
import PySimpleGUI as sg

from tkinter import ttk
from tkPDFViewer import tkPDFViewer as pdf

#Main
class Main(tk.Tk):

    #init main
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        #init tk()
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
  
        SIMPLEGUI_BUTTON = ttk.Button(self, text="SIMPLE GUI", command=lambda: the_gui())
        PDF_Button = ttk.Button(self, text="PDF", command=lambda: PDFWindow())
        SIMPLEGUI_BUTTON.grid()
        PDF_Button.grid()

#simple gui window
def the_gui():
    layout = [[]]

    window = sg.Window('Window', layout)

    while True:
        event, values = window.read()
        if event in (sg.WIN_CLOSED, 'Exit'):
            break

    window.close()

#PDF Window
class PDFWindow(tk.Frame):

    #init main
    def __init__(self):

        #init tk()
        tk.Frame.__init__(self)

        window = tk.Toplevel(self)
        
        v1 = pdf.ShowPdf()
        v2 = v1.pdf_view(master=window, pdf_location="C:\\Users\\Documents\\2021-07-30.pdf", width=200, height=100)
        v2.pack(side="bottom", fill="both")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    app = Main()
    app.mainloop()
```

Traceback:

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 954, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 892, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tkPDFViewer\tkPDFViewer.py", line 49, in add_img
    timg = PhotoImage(data = img)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 4064, in __init__
    Image.__init__(self, 'photo', name, cnf, master, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 4009, in __init__
    self.tk.call(('image', 'create', imgtype, name,) + options)
RuntimeError: main thread is not in main loop
Exception ignored in: <function Variable.__del__ at 0x0000023E408EBDC0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 363, in __del__
    if self._tk.getboolean(self._tk.call("info", "exists", self._name)):
RuntimeError: main thread is not in main loop
```

Comment: Can you please show us the full error traceback? Also what is using `threading`? You can't use any `tkinter` widgets from other threads. But it doesn't look like you are using `threading` your self.

Comment: [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be appreciated (we have an example, but it seems that that example could be minimalized further)

Comment: I've added the traceback and tried to simplify as much as I can. It seems like an issue with something opening a thread somewhere but not closing it properly? Although the traceback suggests tkPDFviewer as the source the issue doesn't actually occur until after the PySimpleGUI window is opened, until that point it will happily open as many times as I want to call it.

Comment: Ok, I've tried a few things extra using threading.enumerate and it seems when I open the PDFViewer window it adds a thread and when I close the tkPDFViewer window the thread keeps going, and everytime I open a new one it adds a new thread.